# Bounding a function above into a ball of radius $R$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $n:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative function. It satisfies
$$n(t) \leq C_1n(0) + C_2$$
where $C_1 > 1$ and $C_2 > 0$.

Is it possible to find a number $R >0$ such that if $n(0) \leq R$, then
$$n(t) \leq R$$
too? $R$ can depend on $C_1$ or $C_2$ but not on $n(t)$ or $n(0)$.

Comment: Why should $n(t) \leq C_1T+C_2 \leq T$?

Comment: @user2943324 no problem

Comment: Can $R$ depend on $T$?

Comment: @youcancallmeAl Yes it can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Let's focus on the smaller class of functions $n$, namely those that  satisfy $n(T)=C_1 n(0)$ and are linear in between $0$ and $T$. Within this class, your question can be stated as: does there exist $R\ge 0$ such that $n(0)\le R$ implies $C_1n(0)\le R$? To which the answer is obviously no: whichever $R$ we pick, the function with $n(0)=R$    gives a counterexample.